# How do I iterate through this table of multiple columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a newbie with collections in PL/SQL, and am trying to use `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL` with a table of a record of **multiple columns**. How can I iterate through the loop?

I tried different syntax options and they all failed. I couldn't find a reference online for **multiple columns** - I can only find examples with a **single column**.

```
--Here are my declarations. Note that there is more than one column in the record. 
--The examples I could find online only use one column:
type mytable_rec is record
(
      mytable_col1 mytable.mytable_col1%type,
      mytable_col2 mytable.mytable_col2%type
);

type mytable_tab is table of mytable_rec;  

l_mytable mytable_tab ;

--I've already loaded my query into l_mytable using bulk collect. 
--Skipping it for readability

forall i in 1 .. l_mytable.count loop --The procedure won't compile 
                                      --because of this line
      update mytable set
             mytable.mytable_col1 = i.mytable_col1,
             mytable.mytable_col2 = i.mytable_col2
       where 1 = 1; --some condition goes here                            
end loop;
```

Trying the following won't work either:

```
forall i in l_mytable.first .. l_mytable.last loop --The procedure won't compile 
                                                   --because of this line
      update mytable set
             mytable.mytable_col1 = i.mytable_col1,
             mytable.mytable_col2 = i.mytable_col2
       where 1 = 1; --some condition goes here                            
end loop;
```

Thanks!

Comment: try the link i think this will help u to understand the implementation as well the process to do it [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html)

Comment: @smn_onrocks Thank you for replying and the link. Unfortunately, that example also uses a single column. If my table is a table of a record that contains multiple columns, how do I iterate through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try the below.please find more information in this link [FORALL Update - Updating multiple columns](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2367352052686)

```
 forall i in l_mytable.first .. l_mytable.last --The procedure won't compile 
                                               --because of this line
  update mytable set
         mytable.mytable_col1 = l_mytable.mytable_col1(i),
         mytable.mytable_col2 = l_mytable.mytable_col2(i)
   where 1 = 1; --some condition goes here
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It still fails on the same line (forall i in l_mytable.first .. l_mytable.last loop):

[Error] Syntax check (2444: 47): Found:  'loop' Expecting: DELETE  EXECUTE  INSERT  MERGE  UPDATE   -or-   SAVE   -or-   +  -  ||   -or-   *  /  MOD  REMAINDER   -or-   **   -or-   (+)  AT  DAY  MULTISET  YEAR   -or-   %  .  [   -or-   (  OVER   -or-   @

Comment: got it forall doesn't require loop keyword

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working. But the index goes next to the table e.g. l_mytable(i).mytable_col1